# Promote instantiated class/object to a class in python?

Tags: python, metaclass

Is there are a way in Python to store instantiated class as a class 'template' (aka promote object to a class) to create new objects of same type with same fields values, without relying on using data that was used to create original object again or on `copy.deepcopy`?

Like, for example I have the dictionary:

```
valid_date = {"date":"30 february"}  # dict could have multiple items
```

and I have the class:

```
class AwesomeDate:
    def __init__(self, dates_dict):
        for key, val in dates_dict.items():
            setattr(self, key, val);
```

I create the instance of the class like:

```
totally_valid_date = AwesomeDate(valid_date)
print(totally_valid_date.date)  # output: 30 february
```

and now I want to use it to create new instances of the `AwesomeDate` class using the `totally_valid_date` instance as a template, i.e. like:

```
how_make_it_work = totally_valid_date()
print(how_make_it_work.date)  # should print: 30 february
```

Is there are way to do so or no? I need a generic solution, not a solution for this specific example.

Comment: I would use a class method defined specifically for unpacking an existing object: `how_make_it_work = awesome_date.from_date(totally_valid_date)`.

Comment: Pretty much sounds like you want prototypal inheritance (like in Javascript). You may just want to implement basic prototypal inheritance from scratch instead of trying to shoehorn a class-based inheritance system into working this way

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the benefit of having a class act both as a template to instances, and as the instance itself, both conceptually and coding-wise. In my opinion, you're better off using two different classes - one for the template, one for the objects it is able to create.

You can think about `awesome_date` as a template class that stores the `valid_date` attributes upon initialization. Once called, the template returns an instance of *a different class* that has the expected attributes.

Here's a simple implementation (names have been changed to generalize the idea):

```
class Thing:
    pass


class Template:
    def __init__(self, template_attrs):
        self.template_attrs = template_attrs
    
    def __call__(self):
        instance = Thing()
        for key, val in self.template_attrs.items():
            setattr(instance, key, val)
        return instance


attrs = {'date': '30 february'}
template = Template(template_attrs=attrs)

# Gets instance of Thing
print(template())  # output: <__main__.Thing object at 0x7ffa656f8668>

# Gets another instance of Thing and accesses the date attribute
print(template().date)  # output: 30 february
```

Comment: I think this is the most sane approach

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are going for something along the lines of the *prototype* design pattern.

## What is the *prototype* design pattern?

> *From [Wikipedia: Prototype pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern)*
>
> The prototype pattern is a creational design pattern in software development. It is used when the type of objects to create is determined by a prototypical instance, which is cloned to produce new objects. This pattern is used to avoid subclasses of an object creator in the client application, like the factory method pattern does and to avoid the inherent cost of creating a new object in the standard way (e.g., using the 'new' keyword) when it is prohibitively expensive for a given application.

> *From [Refactoring.guru: Prototype](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/prototype)*
>
> Prototype is a creational design pattern that lets you copy existing objects without making your code dependent on their classes. The Prototype pattern delegates the cloning process to the actual objects that are being cloned. The pattern declares a common interface for all objects that support cloning. This interface lets you clone an object without coupling your code to the class of that object. Usually, such an interface contains just a single clone method.
> The implementation of the clone method is very similar in all classes. The method creates an object of the current class and carries over all of the field values of the old object into the new one. You can even copy private fields because most programming languages let objects access private fields of other objects that belong to the same class. An object that supports cloning is called a prototype. When your objects have dozens of fields and hundreds of possible configurations, cloning them might serve as an alternative to subclassing. Here’s how it works: you create a set of objects, configured in various ways. When you need an object like the one you’ve configured, you just clone a prototype instead of constructing a new object from scratch.

## Implementing this for your problem, along with your other ideas

From your explanation, it seems like you want to:

- Provide a variable containing a dictionary, which will be passed to the `__init__` of some class `Foo`
- Instantiate class `Foo` and pass the variable containing the dictionary as an argument.
- Implement `__call__` onto class `Foo`, allowing us to use the function call syntax on an object of class `Foo`.
- The implementation of `__call__` will **COPY**/**CLONE** the “template” object. We can then do whatever we want with this copied/cloned instance.

### The Code (edited)

```py
import copy

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *, template_attrs):
        if not isinstance(template_attrs, dict):
            raise TypeError("You must pass a dict to instantiate this class.")
            
        self.template_attrs = template_attrs

    def __call__(self):
        return copy.copy(self)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.template_attrs}"
        
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.template_attrs[key] = value
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.template_attrs:
            raise KeyError(f"Key {key} does not exist in '{self.template_attrs=}'.")
            
        return self.template_attrs[key]

err = Foo(template_attrs=1) # Output: TypeError: You must pass a dict to instantiate this class.

# remove err's assignment to have code under it run
base = Foo(template_attrs={1: 2})
print(f"{base=}") # Output: base={1: 2}
base_copy = base()
base_copy["hello"] = "bye"
print(f"{base_copy=}") # Output: base_copy={1: 2, 'hello': 'bye'}
print(f"{base_copy[1]=}") # Output: base_copy[1]=2
print(f"{base_copy[10]=}") # Output: KeyError: "Key 10 does not exist in 'self.template_attrs={1: 2, 'hello': 'bye'}'."
```

I also added support for subscripting and item assignment through `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` respectively. I hope that this helped a bit with your problem! Feel free to comment on this if I missed what you were asking.

#### Reasons for edits (May 16th, 2022 at 8:49 PM CST | Approx. 9 hours after original answer)

- Fix code based on suggestions by comment from user *jsbueno*
- Handle, in `__getitem__`, if an instance of class `Foo` is subscripted with a key that doesn't exist in the dict.
- Handle, in `__init__`, if the type of `template_attrs` isn't `dict` (did this based on the fact that you used a dictionary in the body of your question)

Comment: Your answer is great on the references, and have a nice impleementation - _save_ for this one line: `globals()[obj_name] = copy.copy(self)` . Do not do that. There is no gain in creating a new class name on the module object where the initial class is defined, with a name that would have to be hardcoded to be used. Instead, just return the copy, it is the caller's responsibility to use it as it sees like (creating a new instance, or even binding to a global name, but on the caller's module)

Comment: **TL;DR**: the body of `def call(self,...):  ` should be just `return copy.copy(self)`

Comment: @jsbueno thanks for the nice words. The reason I did `globals()[obj_name] = copy.copy(self)` was to create a variable that would contain the copied object/instance so you could reference it later and modify it. But, thanks for the input on what would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways to do it -
there could even be some tweaking of inheriting from `type` and meddling with `__call__` to make all instances automatically become derived classes. But I don't think that would be very sane.  Python's own `enum.Enum` does something along this, because it has some use for the enum values - but the price is it became hard to understand beyond the basic usage, even for seasoned Pythonistas.

However, having a custom `__init_subclass__` method that can inject some code to run prior to `__init__` on the derived class, and then a method that will return a new class bound with the data that the new classes should have, can suffice:

```py
import copy
from functools import wraps

def wrap_init(init):
    @wraps(init)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not getattr(self, "_initalized", False):
            self.__dict__.update(self._template_data or {})
            self._initialized = True
        return init(self, *args, **kwargs)
    wrapper._template_wrapper = True
    return wrapper

class TemplateBase:
    _template_data = None
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
        if getattr(cls.__init__, "_template_wraper", False):
            return
        init = cls.__init__
        cls.__init__ = wrap_init(init)


    def as_class(self):
        cls= self.__class__
        new_cls = type(cls.__name__ + "_templated", (cls,), {})
        new_cls._template_data = copy.copy(self.__dict__)
        return new_cls
```

And using it:

```
class AwesomeDate(TemplateBase):
    def __init__(self, dates_dict):
        for key, val in dates_dict.items():
            setattr(self, key, val)
```

On the REPL we have:

```
In [34]: x = AwesomeDate({"x":1, "y":2})

In [35]: Y = x.as_class()

In [36]: y = Y({})

In [37]: y.x
Out[37]: 1
```

Actually, `__init_subclass__` itself could be supressed, and decorating `__init__` could be done in one shot on the `as_class` method. This code takes some care so that mixin classes can be used, and it will still work.